# How to set the default value of a best_in_place checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I'm attempting to modify a Best In Place checkbox that looks like this

```
 best_in_place model, :attribute,
               url: model_path(model),
               as: :checkbox,
               collection: {:false=>"<i class='fa fa-square-o'></i>", :true=>"<i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i>"}
```

We have some cases where we need the checkbox to default to "checked" and also to be disabled, but I can't find a way to do this.  Does Best In Place support this and if so how can I make it happen?

Comment: `best_in_place` does not appear to be maintained anymore; however, have you tried just passing the necessary html options e.g. `checked: "checked", disabled: "disabled"`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the plugin supports this natively, so as a workaround I set the page to conditionally display the HTML ```<i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i>``` if appropriate and show the library output otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things jump out immediately from [the README](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place?tab=readme-ov-file#best-in-place):

> :html_attrs: Hash of html arguments such as maxlength, default-value, etc. that will be set on the rendered input not the best_in_place span.

...and:

> :value: Customize the starting value of the inline input (defaults to to the field's value)